# FosElasticaBundle: how to dump the actual JSON passed to ElasticSearch?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am using FosElasticaBundle in a Symfony project. I configured my mappings but I get exception "expected a simple value for field [_id] but found [START_OBJECT]]".

I'd like to see the actual JSON created by FosElasticaBundle so I can directly test it against my ElasticSearch server, and understand more about the exception.

According to [FosElastica documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/logging.md), everything should be logged when debug mode is enabled (i.e. in DEV environment) but I can't see this happening; I only see Doctrine queries, but no JSON.

How can I dump the JSON created by FosElasticaBundle?

## Update: mappings

```
# FOSElasticaBundle
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: %elasticsearch_host%, port: %elasticsearch_port%, logger: false }
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                user:
                    mappings:
                        name: ~
                        surname: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Comment: Can you show your mapping?

Comment: Sure. But please note that my question is specifically about how to dump the JSON, not about the exception itself. Thank you.

Comment: Your  `logger` configuration is `false`. Have you tried setting it to `true`?

Comment: Epic facepalm. Thank you @Val. If you want to post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only set your `logger` to `true` instead of `false`

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            host: %elasticsearch_host%
            port: %elasticsearch_port%
            logger: true                        <---- set true here
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I totally missed that parameter. It's working as expected. Thank you.