# FosElasticaBundle: define mapping for GUID / UUID fields

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

How do I define the mappings in *config_yml* if my entities uses GUID field type as identifier?

## Details

I have a project with Symfony 2.7.3 and FosElasticaBundle 3.1.4.

I have configured the mapping and everything works fine when I use the *populate* command or if I edit an existing entity; but when creating a new entity I get an exception

```
"expected a simple value for field [_id] but found [START_OBJECT]]"
```

[Checking the JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091629/foselasticabundle-how-to-dump-the-actual-json-passed-to-elasticsearch) I have noticed that *_id* is set to an empty object `..."_id":{}...`.

The **Uuid** class already has a **__toString** method which I expect should do the trick, but I am probably missing something.

## Current mappings

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: %elasticsearch_host%, port: %elasticsearch_port%, logger: true }
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                user:
                    mappings:
                        name: ~
                        surname: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific mappings for UUID/GUID fields.

The identifier is retrieved using the standard Symfony property accessor, so the solution to my problem was to change the `getId()` method in my entity, and make it **cast to string** be

```
public function getId()
{
    return (string)$this->id;
}
```

Comment: P.S. I proposed a PR to FosElasticaBundle so that the identifier is always cast to string when transforming an entity into an ElasticSearch document, but until it gets merged the only solution is in this answer.